# How to do pagination using range queries in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, pagination

I'm probably missing something since I'm still learning the ins and 
outs of MongoDB, but I need help with paging a collection.

I have a collection that has a list of names.

Bottom Round of Beef
Chicken Breast 6oz
Chicken Breast 8oz
Chicken Breast 8oz
Chicken Breast 8oz
Chicken Breast Random
Chicken Legs
Chicken Tenderloin
Chicken Thighs
Kosher Salt

I created a compound index on "ProductName,_id".

I run this query:

```
db.ProductGuideItem.find( { ProductName: { $gt: "Chicken Breast 8oz" } } ).sort({ProductName:1,_id:1}).limit(3);
```

Notice there are 3 "Chicken Breast 8oz" items.

If I run that query I get...
Chicken Breast Random
Chicken Legs
Chicken Tenderloin

If I was paging and started from the top. The query would have missed 
the other 2  "Chicken Breast 8oz".

So if  each page can only have 3 items and I want to see page 2 then I should see..
Chicken Breast 8oz
Chicken Breast 8oz
Chicken Breast Random.

But I'm not. It's going to the last Chicken Breast 8oz and starting from there instead.

Is there a way around this?
Also how would I do this if the list was sorted the opposite way?

Comment: What is your claim? The three returned rows are perfectly fine and matching your query or what do you expect and why?

Comment: First of all relax. Obvously I'm not explaining this correctly. If each page can only have 3 items and I want to see page 2 then I should see Chicken Breast 8oz, Chicken Breast 8oz, Chicken Breast Random. But I'm not. Its going to the last Chicken Breast 8oz and starting from there instead.

Comment: Since I'm doing it wrong how would I get page 2 with the items I listed?

Comment: Read Scott's comments on the list

Comment: Scott's answers appear correct (like always) and there is no different recommendation.

Comment: @Donny, IMO, RestRisiko has a point here (perhaps not not so delicately put, but let's leave it at that). You _could_ have posted a link to your question on the mailing list, so that people who might want to answer you here could first check if the answer they were planning to post wasn't already suggested elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry I'm not the perfect Q/A citizen just wasn't getting answers from the mailing list, so I figured I'd try to get some answers here. I'll post the answer here if I get it on the other list.

Comment: @RestRisiko: Even if this question has been answered somewhere else, it's perfectly valid to ask again unless it's already been asked and answered *here*. If you find reading the same question again to be boring, then there's no need to click the link. StackOverflow is intended to be a community resource, and the questions are, at least in concept, intended to provide answers to more than just the OP, and saying something like "look at the answers to your question on the mailing list" is not particularly helpful in accomplishing that.

Comment: @Donny V.: I agree with @Adam Robinson. You can ask here as long as it's not already asked here. I don't think we owe anything to any other site...

Comment: I have no issues - just with ignorance for perfectly advices and double-asking and unnecessary cross-posts and the attitude asking the question multiple times.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since the collection I was paging had duplicate values I had to create a compound index on ProductName and id.

**Create Compound Index**

```
db.ProductGuideItem.ensureIndex({ ProductName:1, _id:1});
```

This solved my problem.
Reference: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/3EZZIRJzW_A/oYH79npKZHkJ

Assuming you have these values:

```
{a:1, b:1}
{a:2, b:1}
{a:2, b:2}
{a:2, b:3}
{a:3, b:1}
```

So you do this for the range based pagination (page size of 2):

**1st Page**

```
find().sort({a:1, b:1}).limit(2)
{a:1, b:1}
{a:2, b:1}
```

**2nd Page**

```
find().min({a:2, b:1}).sort({a:1, b:1}).skip(1).limit(2)

{a:2, b:2}
{a:2, b:3}
```

**3rd Page**

```
find().min({a:2, b:3}).sort({a:1, b:1}).skip(1).limit(2)
{a:3, b:1}
```

Here are the docs for $min/max:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/min+and+max+Query+Specifiers

If you don't have duplicate values in your collection, you don't need to use min & max or create a compound index. You can just use $lt & $gt.

**Update: 2024**
After revisiting this and making sure nothing new has popped up. I found the article which talks about getting the total count after every page query and doing it all in 1 request. This also takes into consideration if the total document count changes between getting the count and running the query. It uses the aggregate pipeline instead.
https://codebeyondlimits.com/articles/pagination-in-mongodb-the-only-right-way-to-implement-it-and-avoid-common-mistakes

```
exports.getArticles = async (req, res) => {
  let { page, pageSize } = req.query;

  try {
    // If "page" and "pageSize" are not sent we will default them to 1 and 50.
    page = parseInt(page, 10) || 1;
    pageSize = parseInt(pageSize, 10) || 50;

    const articles = await Articles.aggregate([
      {
        $facet: {
          metadata: [{ $count: 'totalCount' }],
          data: [{ $skip: (page - 1) * pageSize }, { $limit: pageSize }],
        },
      },
    ]);

    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      articles: {
        metadata: { totalCount: articles[0].metadata[0].totalCount, page, pageSize },
        data: articles[0].data,
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ success: false });
  }
};
```

Produces an output like this

```
{
  metadata: {
    totalCount: 100,
    page: 1,
    pageSize: 50,
  },
  data: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      title: 'Article 1',
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      title: 'Article 2',
    },
    ...
  ],
};
```

Comment: I think this is an interesting and useful perspective for range based paging on non-unique fields. However, I do not think that your compound index is much use if the _id field is part of the query. The reason is that the _id field is unique, and it will automatically be able to use the default _id index rather than the compound index. See here for the reasoning http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598633/mongodb-unique-index-vs-compound-index

Comment: When using this method you need to force mongodb to use the index `{ ProductName:1, _id:1}` If you don't your results will be out of order.

Comment: This is not suitable for pagination where you display a pagination component (e.g. `Page 1, Page 2, Page 3, ..., Page 10`) to the user, as you cannot randomly click on a `Page #N` link, because for that to work, first you would need the last `ObjectID` for `Page #N-1`.

This is more appropriate for "infinite scroll" pages like Google+, Facebook, or Twitter.

Comment: Actually I ended up creating an index of the first item of every page and using that as a way to jump from one page to another. I was only dealing with a couple hundred items, so it wasn't a big deal. Probably wouldn't scale with a large set.

Answer (score 6):

The below code will return 10 docs form 1st page and similarly for rest of the pages.

```js
const perPage = 10 //10docs in single page
const page = 1 //1st page
db.collection.find({}).skip(perPage * page).limit(perPage)
```