# Ranged pagination when querying & sorting on dynamic, non-unique fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pagination

Ranged pagination is cut and dry when you're paginating based on single unique fields, but how does it work, if at all, in situations with non-unique fields, perhaps several of them at a time?

**TL;DR: Is it reasonable or possible to paginate and sort an "advanced search" type query using range-based pagination?  This means querying on, and sorting on, user-selected, perhaps non-unique fields.**

For example say I wanted to paginate a search for played word docs in a word game.  Let's say each doc has a `score` and a `word` and I'd like to let users **filter and sort** on those fields.  Neither field is unique.  Assume a sorted index on the fields in question.

Starting simple, say the user wants to see all words with a score of 10:

```
// page 1
db.words.find({score: 10}).limit(pp)
// page 2, all words with the score, ranged on a unique _id, easy enough!
db.words.find({score: 10, _id: {$gt: last_id}}).limit(pp)
```

But what if the user wanted to get all words with a score less than 10?

```
// page 1
db.words.find({score: {$lt: 10}}).limit(pp)
// page 2, getting ugly...
db.words.find({
  // OR because we need everything lt the last score, but also docs with
  // the *same* score as the last score we haven't seen yet
  $or: [
    {score: last_score, _id: {$gt: last_id}},
    {score: {$lt: last_score}
  ]
}).limit(pp)
```

Now what if the user wanted words with a score less than 10, and an alphabetic value greater than "FOO"?  The query quickly escalates in complexity, and this is for just *one* variation of the search form with the default sort.

```
// page 1
db.words.find({score: {$lt: 10}, word: {$gt: "FOO"}}).limit(pp)
// page 2, officially ugly.
db.words.find({
  $or: [
    // triple OR because now we need docs that have the *same* score but a 
    // higher word OR those have the *same* word but a lower score, plus 
    // the rest
    {score: last_score, word: {$gt: last_word}, _id: {$gt: last_id}},
    {word: last_word, score: {$lt: last_score}, _id: {$gt: last_id}},
    {score: {$lt: last_score}, word: {$gt: last_word}}
  ]
}).limit(pp)
```

I suppose writing a query builder for this sort of pattern would be doable, but it seems terribly messy and error prone.  I'm leaning toward falling back to skip pagination with a capped result size, but I'd like to use ranged pagination if possible.  Am I completely wrong in my thinking of how this would have to work?  Is there a better way?

### Edit: For the record...

With no viable alternatives thus far I'm actually just using skip based pagination with a limited result set, keeping the skip manageable.  For my purposes this is actually sufficient, as there's no real need to search then paginate into the thousands.

Comment: Skip should only really become slow when you are skipping closer to 100,000 if you setup your database right with the right working set for it, skip will use the index now but it must iterate the entire index upto the skip, so if you seeing maybe a max skip of 10,000 (common max for google results and youtube comments/results) then you should be able to keep with skip

Comment: @Sammaye Thanks Sammaye, yeah that's my current plan.  I'm going with a far smaller limit even, with the thinking that there's no *need* to paginate over large ranges precisely because of the flexibility I'm building into the search.  If the user wants more precise results, they can refine their query options.  Still I think this is an interesting question and I'd like to see if anyone can come up with anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can get ranged pagination by sorting on a unique field and saving the value of that field for the last result. For example:

```
// first page
var page = db.words.find({
    score:{$lt:10},
    word:{$gt:"FOO"}
}).sort({"_id":1}).limit(pp);

// Get the _id from the last result
var page_results = page.toArray();
var last_id = page_results[page_results.length-1]._id;

// Use last_id to get your next page
var next_page = db.words.find({
    score:{$lt:10},
    word:{$gt:"FOO"},
    _id:{$gt:last_id}
}).sort({"_id":1}).limit(pp);
```

Comment: This works to paginate, but it doesn't address the question.  The point is that I need to be able to sort on the non-unique fields for the query to be useful, for example "top scores".  Bolding the relevant part of the question to make this more clear.

Comment: The problem with this is exactly what @numbers1311407 uncovered, you need to actually min/max the index entries to get his scenario working, unfortunately when index intersectioning is brought in it means he will be limited in what he can do

Comment: This will not work. Just sorting on _id would likely skip many documents when requesting the next page. Dependent on the order that documents were created.