# MongoDB ranged pagination when sorting by non-unique field (votes)

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, pagination, mean-stack

I'm currently sorting the data using `find(Less than 'theLatestPost')` and `limit()` approach, but this doesn't work as I try to sort the posts in `upvotes`.

```
db.Posts.find({"_id" : {$lt : ObjectId("51254fa10eba8299c0000000")}}).sort({"_id":-1}).limit(20)
```

PostSchema

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String,
  upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0}
});
```

How can I sort by `upvotes` other than using the `skip()` and `limit()`, since this approach doesn't give the best performance.

Comment: Curious if possible now. Seemed to be unresolved 4 years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819076/ranged-pagination-when-querying-sorting-on-dynamic-non-unique-fields-in-mongo/18822752#18822752