# Paging on collection sorted by compound index?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a compound index that looks like: `{ _id: -1, votes: -1 }` on my `articles` collection  so that I can sort documents by which I can have highly voted articles on top then latest articles after that in a descending order.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to go about paging this collection with the sort order I need because I'm not sure of the order in which the cursor modifies the query.

For example:

`Articles.find().sort('-_id -votes').skip(20).limit(30)`

How would mongodb return documents for that query? Does it modify the cursor based on the order that the commands are executed on the driver or does it reorder them so that limit occurs before sort or anything other than how I think it would execute?

Comment: the cursor finds and then sorts, not on order of commands, as to solving the problem: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5526907/383478

Answer (score 4):

First, as Tyler noted, your index should begin with "votes: -1" if you want to first sort by votes.

Second, to answer your main question: it does not matter what order you apply sort(), skip(), and limit(), so long as you apply them before fetching results from the cursor. A query using these will always sort first, then skip, then return as many documents as specified by limit.

So a query "Articles.find().sort({votes: -1}).skip(20).limit(10)" would skip the 20 highest voted articles and return then 10 after that. But, "Articles.find().sort({votes: -1}).limit(10).skip(20)" would return the same thing! In your specific example, it would skip 20 and then return the 30 documents after that.

For more info, check out the docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the wrong index and sort. What I think you want is articles sorted by votes (descending), then by _id (also descending):

```
{votes: -1, _id: -1}
```

If you sort in that way you'll get articles sorted by votes (with the most first), in creation order.