# Mongodb Aggregation slice

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

So I have a collection oh data and each document has an array of comments, and I need to do a pagination and a sort.I tried something like this, but doesn't work:

```
    $comments = $this->aggregate(array(
        array('$match' => array('_id' => new \MongoId($id))),
        array('$match' => array('comments' => array('$slice' => array($skip,$limit))))
    ));
```

Comment: [How to do pagination using range queries in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525304/how-to-do-pagination-using-range-queries-in-mongodb)

Comment: I don't see how that can help me sort an array inside a collection, I can get that from the collection but I also want to sort that array

Comment: Could you provide example document?

Comment: Post(title,date,comments[0:{title:foo,'text':foo},1:{title:foo,'text':foo},2:{title:foo,'text':foo}]) Just a collection, and every recored has an array of comments, and I also need to sort that array like this : 2,1,0