# What is a good Practice for Pagination using Page Number & Limit in Go?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have created Pagination in Go using Page Number & Limit. Where `Limit & Page Number are INT`

and I created pagination like :

```
MONGO_SESSION.Find(nil).Skip(pageNumber*limit).Limit(limit).Sort("_id").All(&RETURN_STRUCT)
```

It's working fine. But when I send page number or limit ZERO. By default mongo DB return all records because nothing to skip and limit.

> So my question is that what is good practice in case of zero limit and
>   zero page number.
>
> Practice 1: Send all data. Don't send error response.
>
> Practice 2: Send error response saying "Page number and limit can't be
>   zero"

**Note: I can't hardcode limit or page number.**

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This question is somewhat opinion-based (and therefore somewhat off-topic for StackOverflow), but I think some advice or general practice may be helpful and useful for others. So therefore the following of the answer is *my* opinion.

You as the developer of the server application are responsible for the safety and security of the server, and for the utilization of the server's resources. You as the developer should trust clients to the least extent necessary.

That said, sending all documents when client fails to specify the limit (either accidentally or purposefully) is the worst way to handle the situation. It's like screaming out: "Hey, clients and hackers, here's an endpoint, and if you want to [DoS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) my server, just call this endpoint a couple of times".

To protect your server, you should have a safety limit even for the "limit" parameter, because allowing any value for it may be just as bad: just because you force clients to specify a limit doesn't protect your server, "bad" clients may just as well send a limit like `1e9` which will most likely include all your documents.

My advice is to always have *meaningful defaults* and *safety limits*. Default values should always be documented, safety limits are not so important (but could be documented as well).

So how you should handle it is:

1. If limit is missing, apply the defaults. If you can't have defaults, just skip this step (although there must be a good reason not to have / allow a default).
2. Limit should be checked against a safety limit. If it exceeds the safety value, use the safety limit (max allowed limit).
3. If the server has the "right" to alter the requested limit (e.g. using a default when limit is missing, or capping the limit based on a safety limit), the server should communicate back to the client the limit that was actually used to serve the request.

And regarding efficient MongoDB paging: I only recommend using `Query.Skip()` and `Query.Limit()` for "small" document counts. For an efficient paging that "scales" with the number of documents, check out this question+answer: [Efficient paging in MongoDB using mgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40634865/efficient-paging-in-mongodb-using-mgo)

Comment: The problem is that neither I can't define safety limit nor I can't check. Also I don't have last record id.

Comment: Please explain "can't". Are you the developer or not? If you are, you can.

Comment: The situation is that : I got an requirement where nothing return about same anything OR no one is availabel to answer. Some one else have some predefined set of test and gonna test for same. I love to use safety and error responses. So that's the situation. I think I should use safety limit and send error responses.

Comment: The only thing to add here would be to log requests that are trying to exceed the safety limits including the (original) IP (see [XFF](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) if you use a reverse proxy) of the request to be able to react to DoS attacks with something like fail2ban or at least detect it with a SIEM.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Yes, there are a lot more things that could be added in the name of security (such as authentication, rate limiting etc.), I tried to focus on how to handle the `limit` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I believe, that paging should be used only for cases when the size of the collection is big (otherwise just show all the data at once and don't fiddle with paging at all).

However, if the collection is reasonably big, then sending all the data is a bad idea.

There is an additional issue with "skip" statement (it's not unique to mongo though):
in order to skip N records, the db has to do a full scan (full collection scan in case of mongo), so it will take more time to fetch results for page N + 1 than for page N.

Now, in order to deal with it, there is a "trick":
Don't work with skip at all, instead "memorize" the last document id (its already indexed anyway and you sort by `_id` anyway).
Then the queries will be (pseudocode since I don't speak 'Go'):

- For the first query:
  `Find().sort(_id).limit(limitSize)`
- For subsequent queries:
  `Find ().where(_id > lastMemorizedId).sort(_id).limit(limitSize)`

Comment: I don't have lastMemorizedId actually.

Comment: I understand, I'm just stating the possible issues, so if performance aggravation is an issue, probably it worth to be aware of the possible reason.

Comment: So I think sending error response is a good idea. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. I preferred to send Error Response instead of showing all the data.

Because It's a heavy transaction for DB if DB has to send all data. On small collections, it's work fine but for the large collections, it's gonna hang DB.

So send an error response.