# Count Documents That Match a Query in Mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I want to get the count number in a collections based on a field in documents.

According to  [Mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/count/), we can use `runCommand()` to do so.
eg:

```
db.runCommand( { count:'orders',
                 query: { ord_dt: { $gt: new Date('01/01/2012') } }
               } )
```

But how do I do this in MGO?

It seem runcommand is not included in Mgo. I am using mgo.v2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `runCommand()` is available in the `mgo` package as [`Database.Run()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Database.Run). For an example how to use it, see this answer: [Efficient paging in MongoDB using mgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40634865/efficient-paging-in-mongodb-using-mgo/40634866#40634866).

But what you want can simply be achieved by using the [`Query.Count()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Query.Count) method:

```
coll := ... // obtain collection...

count, err := coll.Find(bson.M{"ord_dt": bson.M{
    "$gt": time.Date(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC),
}}).Count()
```