# How to do pagination with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go

I need pagination for Go and MongoDB and I'm highly frustrated with this problem since I cant achieve pagination since weeks now! I dont want to use "Skip" as it is too much resources consuming.

Here is the code:

```
var limit int64 = 20
    var offset int64 = 40

    findOptions0 := options.Find()
    findOptions0.SetLimit(offset)
    findOptions0.SetSort(bson.M{"_id": 1})

    findOptions := options.Find()
    findOptions.SetLimit(limit)
    findOptions.SetSort(bson.M{"_id": 1})

    cursor0, err32 := collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.M{}, findOptions)
    if err32 != nil {
        return status.Errorf(codes.Internal, fmt.Sprintf("Unknown1 internal error: %v", err32))
    }

    for cursor0.Next(context.Background()) {
        err := cursor0.Decode(&data0)
        if err != nil {
            return status.Errorf(codes.Unavailable, fmt.Sprintf("Could not decode data of cursor0: %v", err))
        }

    }

    err := cursor0.Decode(&data0)
    if err != nil {
        return status.Errorf(codes.Unavailable, fmt.Sprintf("Could not decode data of cursor0: %v", err))
    }

    cursor, err34 := collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$gt": data0.ID}}, findOptions)
    if err34 != nil {
        log.Printf("lastID: ", data0.ID)
        return status.Errorf(codes.Internal, fmt.Sprintf("Unknown2 internal error: %v", err34))
    }
    

    for cursor.Next(context.Background()) {
        log.Printf("result: ", cursor)

        // Decode the data at the current pointer and write it to data
        err := cursor.Decode(data)
        // check error
        if err != nil {
            return status.Errorf(codes.Unavailable, fmt.Sprintf("Could not decode data: %v", err))
        }

        log.Printf("End of the for loop ")
```

Comment: Using offset and limit performs only slightly slower for "not too big" offsets, so in practice they are sufficient. If you _really_ need better performance, you have to get, transfer and set the starting index entry for the query. For how it's done with `mgo`, see [Efficient paging in MongoDB using mgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40634865/efficient-paging-in-mongodb-using-mgo/40634866#40634866). The official driver also supports setting the starter index entry, so this is also doable with the official driver.

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting here. If you are taking offset and limit as the input you have to use skip AFAIK. To avoid that, you need to first change the input of your API.

Comment: @icza How is it doable with the official driver? Can you please tell me?

Comment: @Rachel Using [`FindOptions.SetMin()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.4.1/mongo/options#FindOptions.SetMin).

Comment: @icza Is this the better way: https://github.com/icza/minquery ( OR ) FindOptions.SetMin() ???? And which one is the fastest?

and how do we use "newCursor" in this: https://prnt.sc/uua1cg to get the next set of results?

Comment: `github.com/icza/minquery` uses `mgo`, not the official driver. `FindOptions.SetMin()` is the way with the official driver, but that is only to set the starting index entry, it's not the full solution.

Comment: @icza Can you please answer this? https://prnt.sc/uudctb

Comment: @icza And this solution is only for the next set of results so what about if I want previous set of results for previous page in client app?

Comment: @icza Please answer previous questions and I tried your code and it shows so many errors: https://prnt.sc/uudqwi